# C - socket bind() errno 22 - no time-wait sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bind

I am quite new to C & Linux and I tried to setup a TCP socket server for Data exchange with a C-Code I compiled and executed on a Ubuntu System.

From a Tutorial I copied the following code (see below, the original version didn't include exception handling) and it worked to start the server and receive data (time & date) with a client code (on the same machine for test purpose).

Then I restarted the Ubuntu machine and since then I can't start the server anymore.

I then added exception handling to the code below and it throws "unable to bind" with errorno 22, which means "invalid argument"? This doesn't make sense to me, as the same code worked before quite good.

I assumed that the "old" socket is in a time-wait state or not closed yet, but I checked all connections with "ss -all state xxx" for all different states and everything seems alright.

Also tried to use different ports and codes - same problem.

Hope anyone can help me with this problem as I don't know what else to try.

```
// C-Code Server
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char sendBuff[1025];
    time_t ticks; 

    //Open a socket
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 
    if (listenfd == -1) {
        printf("Error: unable to open a socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Create an Adress
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234); 


    //Macht schon benutzte Adresse mit SO_REUSEADDR nutzbar
    int opt = 1;
    if (setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt))<0) {
        perror("setsockopt");exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt))<0)   {
        perror("setsockopt");exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    if ((bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))) == -1) {
        printf("Error: unable to bind\n");
        printf("Error code: %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }



    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

        if (connfd == -1) {
            printf("Error: unable to accept connections\n");
            printf("Error code: %d\n", errno);
            exit(1);
        }



        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
     } 
}
```

Comment: `bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    if ((bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)))` - you bind twice. The second will fail, because the first has taken the port. Just remove the first `bind`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. 

This is one of the exceptions I added myself - seems to be wrong then.

But the original version only contains the first bind comand and still doesn't work/shows the same error.

The original code can be found on "https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/?utm_source=feedburner" (hope I am allowed to post hyperlinks here).

Comment: I removed the first bind and then you're program works successfully on my machine. Check if there is something else listening to the port.

Comment: In any case: `bind()` returns a value. (zero or -1). If this return value is -1, you could (should!) check errno (which *could* be EADDRINUSE)

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will try it tomorrow again and let you guys know if it worked.

Comment: Try a different port.  Check in the file /etc/services because 22 TCP/UDP belongs to ssh(1) daemon.

Comment: Thank you very much - it works again!

I forgot to add "&" when executing my c program (./readpin_socket_server &) so I thought it hanged although the program was just waiting for the client to adress it.